# Is there a best way to set image src in ngFor

Tags: angular, typescript, ngfor

Is there a best way to set image src in ngFor?

I already done that using the following code

```
<li *ngFor="let student of students" >
  <div class="user--image">
   <img [src]="proPicUrl+student.userId" onError="this.src = 'assets/profile.png'" class="card__img" />
  </div>
</li>
```

Is it going to be fast if the image source path comes directly from the server? Is there a chance to reduce processing time?
As you can see the image will be displayed after it gets the students list.

Comment: As much as your code tells, you're doing it the right way. It should not be slow.

Comment: I was curious what will happen if there is more data coming from the server.